# Populate a ListView in fragment correct

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView in a fragment and I want to fill the list with data from a REST API.

The REST request takes 1-3 seconds. 
Now I want to do this in background.

I tried it with

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_watchlist, container, false);
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Execute Request in Thread
            // adapter = ....
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        }
     }, 1000);

     return view;
```

If I debug this function, everything is executed.

But the list is never drawn.

ONLY: If I click on the Search bar on the app main bar. Then I can see the list.

2 days ago everything worked fine. But I dont know where the mistake is.

Here is my Navigation function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_news) {
        fragment = new NewsFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_charts) {
        fragment = new ChartFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_favorites) {
        fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Fragment not Implemented");
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would also agree with sasikumar, break the tasks into smaller methods. Something like 
1. getData() - create a method like this, get data in the background using either AsyncTask, IntentService or a thread. 
2. displayData() - Once you get the data, and parse it and convert it to java object, simply use the java object to populate ur list view.

Comment: But I need to call the displayData() function in my onCreateView() function to get the `View` object of the fragment.
If I try to `getView()` in the displayData() method the view is null

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you call on your REST API oncreateview() of fragment and set adapter in your web api response method(check success).if you want refresh adapter use onResume() method in fragment.

Comment: Do you can explain it more? 
Did you mean the REST API call in `onCreateView` and the adapter assign in `onResume` ?

Comment: set adapter on response of your webApi

Comment: But how can i get the view outside the onCreateView function?